# How should I hash the password in database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, flask

I am trying to hash the passwords stored in users table of the database but for some reason my for loop I use to update the password is running for 5999 time and i have only 500 rows in my table in database.
Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong. I am really stuck from a long time. Thank you!

[image: the picture shows that the loop is running for 5999 times]

Below is the app.py in which the loop in hash_password() function

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
import sqlite3 as sql
import uuid 
import hashlib

#set up our application
app = Flask(__name__)
host = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
app.secret_key = "super secret key"

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    hash_password()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        pw_hash = make_pw_hash(password)
        print(pw_hash)
        result = valid_email_password(email, pw_hash)
        if result:
            return render_template('profile.html', error=error, result=result)
        else:
            flash('invalid email or password')
            error = 'invalid email or password'

    return render_template('login.html', error = error)

@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html')

#helper for login
def valid_email_password(email, password):
    connection = sql.connect('database.db')
    connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(email TEXT PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT);')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * FROM users WHERE (email, password) = (?, ?)', (email, password))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    if user is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def make_pw_hash(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).hexdigest()

#function that was used to hash all the passwords stored in the database
def hash_password():
    connection = sql.connect('database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    i = 0
    for user, p in cursor:
        print(p)
        hash_password = hashlib.sha256(str.encode(p)).hexdigest()
        connection.execute("UPDATE users set password = ? WHERE email = ?", (hash_password, user)) 
        print("new_p:", p, i)     
        i += 1
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

[image: some part of database shown below]

Comment: 1) If you're looping SQL statements, there's probably a better way. You can do your hashing in a single update. 2) SHA256 is not a good choice for password hashing anymore, it's too fast. 3) With no salt, you're vulnerable to rainbow table attacks. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html for more.

Comment: Do you know how I can do hashing in a single update? I was only able to figure out how to do hashing this way. @Schwern